# How do I read / write a file in Python (3) on Windows without introducing carriage returns?

Tags: python, regex, file, python-3.x

I want to open a file using Python on Windows, perform some regex operations, optionally alter the content and then write the result back to a file.

I can create an example file which looks right (based on the comments on using binary mode in other posts on SO and within the documentation). What I can't see is how I convert the 'binary' data to a usable form without introducing '\r' characters.

An example:

```
import re

# Create an example file which represents the one I'm actually working on (a Jenkins config file if you're interested).
testFileName = 'testFile.txt'
with open(testFileName, 'wb') as output_file:
    output_file.write(b'this\nis\na\ntest')

# Try and read the file in as I would in the script I was trying to write.
content = ""
with open(testFileName, 'rb') as content_file:
    content = content_file.read()

# Do something to the content
exampleRegex = re.compile("a\\ntest")
content = exampleRegex.sub("a\\nworking\\ntest", content) # <-- Fails because it won't operate on 'binary data'

# Write the file back to disk and then realise, frustratingly that something in this process has introduced carriage returns onto every line.
outputFilename = 'output_'+testFileName
with open(outputFilename, 'wb') as output_file:
    output_file.write(content)
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'without introducing carriage returns'? They are already in the file. Am I correct in understanding that your requirement is to read the whole file as one continuous string(by getting rid of carriage returns) that you can run regular expressions on? So essentially your regular expressions can cross line boundaries and you don't want to factor that in your regular expressions, right?

Comment: I'm interpreting the question as "when I open a file without the 'b' flag, then sometimes '\n' characters get converted to '\r\n', which is undesirable. But when I open a file with the 'b' flag, I can't use `re.sub`. How can I use `sub` while preventing automatic newline conversion?"

Comment: @Paani: If I open without the 'b' option, Python adds `\r` to each line. If I open with the binary option, I then can't do any string operations because they see it as binary data.

Comment: Just a note - the failure behaviour above is for Python 3 only - I'd consider tagging this with python-3.x and mentioning Python 3 in the text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I presume you mean, your text file has return carriages and you don't want them included in the text.

If you use
        `with open(fileName, 'r', encoding="utf-8", errors="ignore", newline="\r\n") as content_file`

or more specifically, set newline="\r\n" in your open call, it should consume the return carriages on new lines.

Edit: Or if you want to operate only on `\n` then this working example should do it.

```
import re

testFileName = 'testFile.txt'
with open(testFileName, 'w', newline='\n') as output_file:
    output_file.write('this\nis\na\ntest')

content = ""
with open(testFileName, 'r', newline='\n') as content_file:
    content = content_file.read()

exampleRegex = re.compile("a\\ntest")
content = exampleRegex.sub("a\\nworking\\ntest", content)

outputFilename = 'output_'+testFileName
with open(outputFilename, 'w', newline='\n') as output_file:
    output_file.write(content)
```

Comment: No, the file just has '\n' line endings. The problem is that if I read / write without using the `'b'` option Python adds `'\r'` to each line.

Comment: If you explicitly state the newline used when you open the files, your problem will go away and I don't think you will need to use 'b'.

Comment: @JonCage What if you specify `newline="\n"` for the output file?

Comment: Looks like you're right. In fact, it looks like you just need to add it on the output if the file you're reading in a file without carriage returns in it.

Comment: Just adding `\r\n` as the newline on the input file isn't enough.

Comment: Not 100% sure about Windows, but py3 should convert variations of newline to `'\n'` when reading, if using "universal mode" with conversion, aka `newline=None` (the default in text mode). `newline=''` on the other hand treats the different variations as line separators, but will not translate. The other modes (`'\n'`, `'\r'` etc.) will only treat those as newlines.

Comment: If you require having `\n` rather than `\r\n` in your output file then you can specify that for your output. So `with open(fileName, 'r', newline="\n")` as content_file should give you a file that writes newlines that ignores the environment standard.

Answer (score 1):

If I interpreted the question correctly, I first decoded the bytes to string, then did the regex sub. Next, I encoded the string into bytes to be written into the output file.

```
import re

testFileName = 'testFile.txt'
with open(testFileName, 'wb') as output_file:
    output_file.write(b'this\nis\na\ntest')

content = ""
with open(testFileName, 'rb') as content_file:
    content = content_file.read().decode('utf-8')

exampleRegex = re.compile("a\\ntest")
content = exampleRegex.sub("a\\nworking\\ntest", content)

outputFilename = 'output_'+testFileName
with open(outputFilename, 'wb') as output_file:
    output_file.write(content.encode('utf-8'))
```

Comment: Whilst this does work, specifying '`\n'` on the output requires less code.